# select one to one relationship in one to many table structure

Tags: mysql

I have three MySql tables:-

- tbl_part - Contains a list of parts with a part_id
- tbl_product - Contains a list of products with a product_id
- tbl_part_to_product - Contains one to many relationships between parts and products (part_id & product_id)

I'm trying to do two things:-

1. Select all products that only have one part.
2. Find all products that only have a specific part as there **only** part.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT
*
FROM
tbl_part part
INNER JOIN tbl_part_to_product p2p ON part.part_id = p2p.part_id
INNER JOIN tbl_product prod ON p2p.product_id =prod.product_id
WHERE part.name = 'whatever'
GROUP BY prod.product_id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
```

To select all products that only have one part just delete the WHERE clause.

If you don't want to join to the parts table:

```
SELECT
*
FROM
tbl_product prod
INNER JOIN tbl_part_to_product p2p ON p2p.product_id =prod.product_id
GROUP BY prod.product_id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
```

Comment: This selects all parts, not products.

Comment: No, it doesn't. If it makes you feel more comfi you can replace `SELECT *` with `SELECT prod.*`

Comment: Does it make any difference if you don't use the parts table?

Comment: No, it doesn't. You have to rewrite the join, though. Updated my answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

Let's address both questions:

Select all products that only have one part.

```
SELECT tbl_product.*
FROM
tbl_product product
INNER JOIN tbl_part_to_product ptop ON ptop.product_id = product.product_id
GROUP BY product.product_id
HAVING COUNT(ptop.part_id) = 1
```

Find all products that only have a specific part as there only part.

```
SELECT tbl_product.*
FROM
tbl_product product
INNER JOIN tbl_part_to_product ptop ON ptop.product_id = product.product_id
INNER JOIN tbl_part part ON ptop.part_id = part.part_id
WHERE part.part_name = 'some name'
GROUP BY product.product_id
HAVING COUNT(ptop.part_id) = 1
```

If you get GROUPing errors from either query, you need to add all the tbl_product fields to the GROUP.